# How to inject custom tags into OpenTelemetry when using a side-car pattern

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, dapr, sidecar

I am new to OpenTelemetry. I am trying to understand how to set up custom tags when using a side-car Observability pattern as [DAPR](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/monitoring/tracing/open-telemetry-collector/).
My point is to find a way to add OpenTelemetry tags to a Trace in an app service.DAPR side-car container inject traceId, spanId etc. I have setup [sample](https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/598715117e17e9dcbdeb30ea78ff0da1638e76c2/tutorials/distributed-calculator) app on Kubernetes. I have modified the C# class *SubtractController* like this:

```
//POST: /subtract
    [HttpPost]
    public decimal Subtract(Operands operands)
    {
        //from here:
        using var source = new ActivitySource("Subtract");
        using var activity = source.StartActivity(
                            "",
                            ActivityKind.Consumer);
        activity?.SetTag("MyGreatTag", "here!");
        //to here.

        Console.WriteLine($"Subtracting {operands.OperandTwo} from {operands.OperandOne}"); 
        return Decimal.Parse(operands.OperandOne) - Decimal.Parse(operands.OperandTwo);
    }
```

Essentially I've tried to inject a tracing tag with *System.Diagnostics* lib. However in Zipkin this tag is absent. So  I assume it does not work. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. I would modify your code a bit to use Baggage to pass along custom properties like below.

```
var activity = new Activity("Subtract");
activity.setBaggage("propertyName", "value");
activity.Start();

try {
  doWork();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  // handle exception
}
finally {
  activity.Stop();
}
```

Then in the context where the method `doWork()` resides, you should be doing something like this to retrieve the baggage value.

```
var activity = new Activity("doWorkOperation");
string? baggageValue = activity.GetBaggageItem("propertyName");
```